# Commas in gnuplot labels

Tags: gnuplot, currency, label

I'm plottng monetary data with gnuplot and currently I've managed to set the labels on the y axis to be floating point values with no decimals (rather than exponentials) but I want to be able to add comma's to the label but I cant figure out how.

Any ideas?

i.e. The current output gives me £25000000 - as you can see, the data isn't grouped - I want to split it in thousands so it appears as £25,000,000.

EDIT:
My current setting is

`set format y '£%.0f'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As stated [here](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_4.2/gnuplot.html#x1-46000053) the thousands separator depends on the locale-specific formatting.
If this setting allows for the thousands separator it will be printed with:

```
set decimal locale
set format y "%'g"
plot 1000*x
```

An other option would be to set the ytics manually ([see here](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_4.2/gnuplot.html#x1-29800043.89)) like so:

```
set ytics ("5,000,000" 5000000, "10,000,000" 10000000, "15,000,000" 15000000, "20,000,000" 20000000, "25,000,000" 25000000)
plot[0:3] 10000000*x
```

Comment: The C local file would be somewhere in my Macports settings? (Running gnuplot via Macports on OSX 10.7).

My current setting is

`set format y '£%.0f'`

Comment: Try `set format y '£%'.0g'`. (Note the little "inverted comma" behind the percentage sign.)

Comment: Gnuplot complains then (until I replaced the end ' with ") and when I do that, the inverted comma makes no difference.

Comment: @drezha You are correct, it should be set like this `format y "£%'.0g"`. Please issue the commands: `set decimal locale; show locale` and post the output. My output says: `gnuplot LC_NUMERIC en_US.UTF-8` which enables the thousand separators.

Comment: Mine shows up as

`gnuplot LC_CTYPE   en_GB.UTF-8
 gnuplot encoding   default
 gnuplot LC_TIME    en_GB.UTF-8
 gnuplot LC_NUMERIC C`

Comment: That C seems to be the error from googling (ie LC_NUMERIC would give me the thousand seperator, LC_NUMERIC C doesn't. 

Now all I have to do is try and change it somehow!

Comment: No idea how to change the Numeric setting?

Comment: Managed it in the end. I'd missed out your `set decimal locale` step. Adding that to every file changed it `LC_NUMERIC C` into `LC_NUMERIC en_GB.UTF8`